# Chi square distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

K is chi-square distributed with 33 as degree of freedom. P(x ≤ K ≤ y) = 0,73 and the probability of the above and below [x,y] is equal. I'm supposed to define x and y.

I tried solving it like this:

0,73/2 = 0,365

P(x≤K) = X^2 0,365 (33) = 35,18628

P(K≥y) = X^2 (1-0,365) (33) = 29,64383

I used Excel's =CHIINV(0,365;33) formula for the answers but apparently they are incorrect. What did I do wrong and how should I have done it?

Comment: I'm still looking for help with this. Any hints anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is that if $$\Pr[x \le K \le y] = 0.73, \quad \Pr[K < x] = \Pr[K > y],$$ then since $$\Pr[K < x] + \Pr[x \le K \le y] + \Pr[K > y] = 1,$$ then $$\Pr[K < x] = \Pr[K > y] = (1 - 0.73)/2 = 0.135.$$  So we can use the quantile function of the $\chi^2$-distribution to get $y = 42.0189$, and $x = 24.271$.  Note that in Excel, `CHIINV(p, df)` gives a number $x$ such that $\Pr[K > x] = p$, for $K \sim \chi^2(df)$.  That is to say, $p$ is an upper quantile.  So to get $y$ as above, you need to type in `CHIINV(0.135, 33)` and to get $x$, you need to type in `CHIINV(1-0.135, 33)`.